# How to calculate day difference between rows with specific conditions in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner of Pandas.
I have a dataframe like below and want to calculate the "CV" day difference since "Visit" per "ID", as the "CV_days_after_visit" in the expected result.    
May I know how I can achieve this with Pandas in Python

```
import pandas as pd
data1 = {'ID': ['A2A', 'A2A', 'A2A', 'BB3', 'BB3', 'BB3', '5EE', '5EE'], 'Action': ['Visit', 'CV', 'CV', 'Visit', 'Visit', 'CV', 'Visit', 'CV'], 'date': ['2023/4/1', '2023/4/5', '2023/4/7', '2023/5/5', '2023/5/29', '2023/5/30', '2023/6/1', '2023/6/10']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data1)

print (df)
    ID  Acton       date
0  A2A  Visit   2023/4/1
1  A2A     CV   2023/4/5
2  A2A     CV   2023/4/7
3  BB3  Visit   2023/5/5
4  BB3  Visit  2023/5/29
5  BB3     CV  2023/5/30
6  5EE  Visit   2023/6/1
7  5EE     CV  2023/6/10
```

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are sorted `ID` with `date` in real data like in sample?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can subtract forward filling by [`GroupBy.ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ffill.html) dates if `Visit` by [`Series.sub`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.sub.html) and convert timedeltas to days by [`Series.dt.days`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.days.html), last if necessary remove `0` days by [`Series.mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html):

```
#convert column to datetimes
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

m = df['Acton'].eq('Visit')
df['CV_days_after_visit'] = (df['date'].sub(df['date'].where(m).groupby(df['ID']).ffill())
                                       .dt.days
                                       .mask(m))
print (df)
    ID  Acton       date  CV_days_after_visit
0  A2A  Visit 2023-04-01                  NaN
1  A2A     CV 2023-04-05                  4.0
2  A2A     CV 2023-04-07                  6.0
3  BB3  Visit 2023-05-05                  NaN
4  BB3  Visit 2023-05-29                  NaN
5  BB3     CV 2023-05-30                  1.0
6  5EE  Visit 2023-06-01                  NaN
7  5EE     CV 2023-06-10                  9.0
```

How it working:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

m = df['Acton'].eq('Visit')

print (df.assign(m1 = df['date'].where(m),
                 ffill = df['date'].where(m).groupby(df['ID']).ffill(),
                 sub = df['date'].sub(df['date'].where(m).groupby(df['ID']).ffill()),
                 days = df['date'].sub(df['date'].where(m).groupby(df['ID']).ffill())
                                  .dt.days))

    ID  Acton       date         m1      ffill    sub  days
0  A2A  Visit 2023-04-01 2023-04-01 2023-04-01 0 days     0
1  A2A     CV 2023-04-05        NaT 2023-04-01 4 days     4
2  A2A     CV 2023-04-07        NaT 2023-04-01 6 days     6
3  BB3  Visit 2023-05-05 2023-05-05 2023-05-05 0 days     0
4  BB3  Visit 2023-05-29 2023-05-29 2023-05-29 0 days     0
5  BB3     CV 2023-05-30        NaT 2023-05-29 1 days     1
6  5EE  Visit 2023-06-01 2023-06-01 2023-06-01 0 days     0
7  5EE     CV 2023-06-10        NaT 2023-06-01 9 days     9
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!! It worked! I will study the logic of the codes

Answer (score 1):

You can work like this, that's less straightforward than previous answer but if you're a beginner I think it could be clearer as the commands are really basic:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

# Sort the DataFrame by 'ID' and 'date'
df = df.sort_values(by=['ID', 'date'])

# Filter rows where 'Action' is 'CV'
cv_rows = df[df['Action'] == 'CV']

# Find the last visit date for each ID
last_visit_dates = df[df['Action'] == 'Visit'].groupby('ID')['date'].last().reset_index()
last_visit_dates.columns = ['ID', 'last_visit_date']

# Merge last visit dates with CV rows
cv_rows = pd.merge(cv_rows, last_visit_dates, on='ID')

# Calculate the difference in days between CV date and last visit date
cv_rows['CV_days_after_visit'] = (cv_rows['date'] - cv_rows['last_visit_date']).dt.days

# Merge the calculated CV days after visit back to the original DataFrame
df = pd.merge(df, cv_rows[['ID', 'date', 'CV_days_after_visit']], on=['ID', 'date'], how='left')
```